# Mac OS X (latest version) - cant find .screenrc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unix, rvm, gnu-screen, screenrc

very simple question:  I'm using latest version of Mac OS and want to modify my .screenrc file...
can't find the file.  I have made invisible files visible via Finder *and*  I have also searched for it via the command line.

I have searched for it via the obvious directory structure from my $HOME directory, and I have gone to root and tried searching for it there... all searches yield no results.

I have search using the actual name and partial string with wildcards... what am I missing?

Comment: Could you include the command line you used to search for the file in your question for completeness please.

Comment: @Levon thank you for the feedback - I'm new to this site, so it's nice to be reminded about proper 'form'... :) I was able to the get my issue resolved

Comment: happy it all worked out. Getting used to SO takes some time, I'm still trying to figure things out myself :) .. in general the more relevant information  you can provide, the better.

Answer (score 4):

> What am I missing?

You need to create it, as one will not exist by default.

Just to double-check that it doesn't exist, open Terminal.app & type:

```
ls -al ~/.screenrc
```

If it returns nothing, then it doesn't exist.

To create:

```
touch ~/.screenrc
```

Comment: awesome!! thanks for the prompt reply!  that worked.  I started to create one yesterday, but wanted to make sure I had thoroughly looked everywhere and exhausted other options  - thanks again for the help, as I knew this question was basic ... :/